# Examples where homogeneity is better proved via atomicity

Tags: logic, examples-counterexamples, model-theory

Countable atomic structures are homogeneous, i.e., all finite tuple of the same first-order type are conjugate under automorphisms.  While this is classical, I can't think of an example of a countable structure whose homogeneity is best proved via atomicity.  Competing proof strategies include construction of that structure as a Fraisse limit possibly in an expanded language.

Is there a countable structure whose homogeneity is proved via atomicity in a manner at least as good (whatever that means) as via Fraisse theory?

Comment: How about $(\mathbb{N},<)$?

Comment: @AlexKruckman That'll work.